# Is there a way to add data annotations on on methods input parameters?

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, data-annotations

I have the following code:

```
 public void Foo(
                 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Null not allowed")]
                 [ModelValidation] //custom validation
                 UserModel user
                 )
    {
          //Do some code
    }
```

Is there a way that upon calling this method to validate the input according to the data annotations?

Comment: I don't think you understand what attributes actually do. On their own they do absolutely nothing, it's the framework that reads them and behaves accordingly. For example, ASP.NET MVC Core is the framework that likely uses these attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay.
Just want to make sure that I can't run console application and expect that validation occurs according to the data annotation?

Comment: No, having data attributes in logic that does not use them will result in nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the documentation to your end-users, you can use `<param>` annotation for your input parameters like this -

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method validates and submits your report for processing 
    /// </summary>    
    /// <param name="ReportName">This is the name of your report</param>
    /// <param name="ReportTotalUSD">This is the total amount in USD</param>
    /// <param name="ReportDate">This is the date you incurred expenses</param>

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<int>))]
    public IHttpActionResult SubmitReport(string ReportName, decimal ReportTotalUSD, DateTime ReportDate)
```